# Using empty matrix as an index of another matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to translate a piece of 'for' loop code from Matlab to Python. And there is one statement in this block: `A[B]=C`. All those three A, B and C are matrices. In python, I need to write as    `A[B-1]=C`, because of the difference of index criteria between Matlab and Python. 
  When B is non-empty, this statement goes well in python. However, if B is empty, this statement goes like this:

```
A11 = np.copy(A[:,B-1]) #Remind that B is an empty matrix, like B=np.array([0])
```

**IndexError:arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type**

Actually, if B is empty, what I want to have for matrix A11 is just another empty matrix. Definitely I can use a if block to define what matrix A11 should be when B is an empty matrix. But it will be too fussy because I have another 5 statement like this kind of using matrix as an index. Could you give me an example that shows me how to fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B = np.array([0])` does not generate an empty matrix, it just converts the list `[0]` into a numpy array.

I suppose you meant something like `B = np.zeros(0)` (where the argument is a shape). Numpy's default is `dtype =float64` but in order to use an array for indexing integer or boolean type is required. For a non-empty array with values that are in fact integers numpy figures out that it can just change the `dtype`.

To fix your problem you can simply specify the `dtype` (to int or boolean) when you initialize it, i.e. `B = np.zeros(0, dtype=np.int)` works fine. `A` will then be an 'empty matrix' in the sense that one of its shape dimensions is 0 - the others however do not change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried to generate 'B' using your code:`np.zeros(0, dtype=np.int)`. And then extract some part from matrix A using that empty matrix B. Compared with the empty matrix I used before, it's element are 'float64' type. It seems that the question is we have to transfer the dtype of matrix B from **float64** to **int32**? Thx for your help!

Comment: Any int or bool type should work. If you actually want the `dtype` to be **float64**, using the matrix B for indexing won't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Really appreciate that!